# Iphone 6 game view dimension changing on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, scale, iphone-6

I created a SpriteKit game and it works well except when I turn my Iphone 6 view mode to zoomed the game looks like zoomed too.

When I return to the standard mode everything goes back and looks just. I create the nodes in the right dimensions. Like it works on Iphone simulator.

I tried to change the scale mode in `GameViewController` and nothing changes, I still have the same problem.

Comment: post your code .. and improve your description, it's unclear what kind of scale problem you have and where it occurs (only the iPhone 6, or the iPhone 6 Simulator as well?), and what you mean by "zoom".

Comment: I have The Problem On IPhone 6 . If You Know there is an option in iphone 6 sittings let you change the view to zoomed view with large icons . here you can found out what i mean http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203073